# Using a single column table for generation sequence in SQL Server 2008 is scalable solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently we are relying on a formula for generating confirmation numbers, but on heavy loads we observed duplicate confirmation numbers are being generated. We are considering switching to a sequence table as a quick fix, but we're worried about how it will perform. How can we calculate the risk in using the following approach?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TRN_CNFRM_SEQUENCE_UC_LOC_1 
(
       id INT IDENTITY(seed,increment)
)

declare @confirm table (id int);
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO dbo.TRN_CNFRM_SEQUENCE_UC_LOC_1 
       output inserted.id into @confirm
DEFAULT VALUES
ROLLBACK TRAN
select ID from @confirm
```

Comment: No, `SET @Confrm = (SELECT isnull
            (MAX(CONVERT(int, TRN_CNFRM_NBR)),0) 
            FROM TRANSACTION_MAIN WHERE
            TRN_UC_LOC = @1) + 1;` this piece of code is producing duplicates, The above said sql script is the solution that i am going to implement.

Comment: I assume you are not using SQL Server 2012, otherwise you would just use a SEQUENCE, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using SqlServer 2008

Answer (score 1):

First, creating a memory table means a table will be created in tempdb requiring schema lock. Adding a row to that table requires an additional exclusive page lock. If you're only acquiring a single "confirmation number" at the time you could get around that by altering the code to:

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO dbo.TRN_CNFRM_SEQUENCE_UC_LOC_1
DEFAULT VALUES
ROLLBACK TRAN
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Inserting into the table will also require an exclusive page lock. Having a high degree of concurrent work loads can lead to latch contention on the single page this table will allocate.